# Get desktop notifications from application

Tags: node.js

I've created a NodeJS application which scrapes and parses the contents of a web page at regular intervals, checking if certain things on the web page have been updated since the last time it was parsed. The application runs locally, in the background.

I need the application to be able to provide me with some sort of a notification for when these things are updated. Is there any way that the application can show a tooltip in the Windows tray area, or provide any other sort of notification to me?

The only thing I can find is node-notify (https://github.com/olalonde/node-notify), but that appears to be for Ubuntu. As a last resort, I could have the application run a local web server and update the contents of a page based on whether anything on the scraped web page has been updated, then use something else entirely (e.g. an AutoHotkey script) which checks the page on the local web server to see if anything has changed, and use that to display the tooltips. Obviously, it would be much easier if the application itself could notify me in some way.

Comment: What OS do you need this on. Would something like Growl work?

Comment: Windows is the OS I'll be running this on. Growl looks like it might be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`node-growl` module from visionmedia](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-growl).
You just need to install [Growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx) and [growlnotify](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/growlnotify.aspx) manually and then the node module with:

```
npm install growl
```

Then, it's as easy as doing:

```
var growl = require('growl');
growl('Hello World!');
```

There are more examples (including use of images) on the [projects' site](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-growl).

Answer (score 3):

While Growl is definitely the more visually appealing option, I'd like to propose [Notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/) as an alternative for future readers of this question.

Fair warning: it has not been updated since Feb 2010, but still...

- It does still work on Win7.
- It does not require any additional software to be installed on the computer.
- It can be packaged with the Node.js app.
- Can be easily integrated using any of the numerous Node modules for running system commands.